# Why Does FDT 5.5 Not Find My Flex SDKs?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, installation, fdt

I've downloaded the latest Flex SDKs from Adobe; however, when FDT asks me to locate the SDKs it doesn't find them.

I've also tried to search in FDT's plugin folder:

plugins/com.powerflasher.fdt.shippedFlexSDK4_4.5.0.20967_1000
plugins/com.powerflasher.fdt.shippedFlexSDK_3.6.0.16995_1000

Answer (score 8):

FDT needs two things to find a valid SDK:

1. The SDK needs to be unzipped.
2. There needs to be a valid 'flex-sdk-description.xml' file.

Only then can FDT find an SDK.

The folders in FDT's 'plugins' folder are obsolete and contain nothing. They will be removed in future versions of FDT.